# use javascript away from HTML and Internet-Browsers and make a pop-up message

Tags: javascript, popup, message, messagebox

I was following [THIS](https://www.phpied.com/make-your-javascript-a-windows-exe/) tutorial, where it's shown how to make your js-file into an exe.

My first *.exe was just `print("hello world")`. I succeeded easily, we all did that at one time.

The next thing that I wanted to do was a pop-up window (maybe with a button).

There I realized when googling for methods it was all in HTML / Web context. And that the window object is somehow generated inside the ??browser??

> How can I get a popup Message without any Browsers and HTML files.

Can I use js and stay miles away from Web and HTML? Is there any js resources without any embeddedness in HTML.

Hope my question is clear enough.

Comment: Look at the bottom of the tutorial you linked to. There is a code example.

Comment: @Weedoze — `print("Hellow world")` is JavaScript. There are many applications for JavaScript that don't involve web browsers.

Comment: do you guys have any good recourse for js learning without HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get input and show message box :

```
import System.Windows.Forms;
import Microsoft.VisualBasic;
var input = Interaction.InputBox("Question?","Title","Default Text");
MessageBox.Show(
     "input: " + input,
      "title",
     MessageBoxButtons.OK,
     MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation
);
```

Comment: however , why would some one use this on 2017 ? there is a lot of easier ways if you just try to learn